# CSS z-index issue

Tags: css

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lk4s/

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="c1"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
</div>
```

I try to display .c1 and .c2 behind .box (so box has a higher z-index and all three classes have position:relative set), but I can't get it to show up this way.

What is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.c1` and `.c2` are part of `.box` (as they are child element of it) if you want them to be behind it they have to be separated elements

Also to position behind `.box` the easiest way is to position absolute them see: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lk4s/1/

For more documentation on how z-index works see the w3c spec thanks to @Joseph Silber: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html#painting-order

Comment: +1 this is how it's supposed to be according to the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html#painting-order

Comment: @amosrivera but I want .c1 and .c2 to be inside .box when I show up my page... I would have to hack by doing position:relative and top:-50px?

Comment: @Adam Strudwick it probably can be done some other way, why do you want to position them behind .box?

Comment: @amosrivera Well it is in the context of a more elaborate web page design ... here I simplified the problem for the sake of people on Stackoverflow who don't want to know every detail of my projects ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `.box` is the parent element to `.c2`

If you still wanted to go with having that `.box` area to restrict `.c2` positioning, you could do it like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lk4s/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lk4s/3/ - Another example to show that `.c2` positioning is restricted by the outer box rather than document.

HTML:

```
<div class="outerbox">

    <div class="box">
        <div class="c1"> </div>
    </div>
        <div class="c2"> </div>

</div>
```

Added CSS:

```
.outerbox { position: relative; float: left; }
```